# Posit with keycloak authentication, client_not_found and reason Cannot_match_source_hash

Tags: rstudio, keycloak

When trying to setup keycloak authentication for Posit, I'm running into the `client_not_found and reason Cannot_match_source_hash` error. I've seen post about IdPEntityID not being matched, but am unsure on how to match them in this situation.

The request seems to be getting to keycloak, but the screen the shows:

```
We are sorry... Invalid request

Keycloak event Posit Realm:

reason  Cannot_match_source_hash

error    client_not_found

Worked with Posit support

Will try adding adding additional info after post since I'm either being accused of spam or too many links for a newbie



> SAML entries from rstudio-connect.gcfg:
> 
> [SAML] ; SSOInitiated = IdP IdPMetaDataURL =
> `https://example.com/realms/Posit/protocol/saml/descriptor`
> IdPAttributeProfile = default ; the unique identifier for a user over
> time UniqueIdAttribute = NameID ; UniqueIdAttribute = GUID
> NameIDFormat = emailAddress  ; NameIDFormat = persistent  ;
> NameIDFormat = transient UsernameAttribute = Username 
> FirstnameAttribute = FirstName  LastnameAttribute = LastName 
> EmailAttribute = Email  GroupsAttribute = Groups SPEncryptionKey =
> /certs/skccapp02pa-private.pem SPEncryptionCertificate =
> /certs/skccapp02pa.pem ; Enable this for a better user experience,
> unless ; managing a large number of groups is a concern:
> GroupsAutoProvision = true ; When attempting to troubleshoot a problem
> relating to SAML, ; you can enable more verbose logging by enabling
> the following line Logging = true IdPSingleSignOnPostBinding = true  ;
> IdPEntityID = `https://example.com/realms/Posit`  ; IdPEntityID =
> `https://example.com/realms/Posit/protocol/saml/descriptor`
> ;IdPSingleSignOnServiceURL = https://example.com/login


My IdPMetaDataURL returns:

<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns=`urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata` xmlns:md=`urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata` xmlns:saml=`urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion` xmlns:ds=`http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#` entityID=`https://example.com/realms/Posit`> <md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned=`true` protocolSupportEnumeration=`urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol`> <md:KeyDescriptor use=`signing`> <ds:KeyInfo> <ds:KeyName>B0kqI7fTz_kBGW7oRmkR503LneQZL-9cApupjbyuUEE</ds:KeyName> <ds:X509Data> <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate> </ds:X509Data> </ds:KeyInfo> </md:KeyDescriptor> <md:ArtifactResolutionService Binding=`urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP` Location=`https://example.com/realms/Posit/protocol/saml/resolve` index=`0`/> <md:SingleLogoutService Binding=`urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST` Location=`https://example.com/realms/Posit/protocol/saml`/> <md:SingleLogoutService Binding=`urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect` Location=`https://example.com/realms/Posit/protocol/saml`/> <md:SingleLogoutService Binding=`urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact` Location=`https://example.com/realms/Posit/protocol/saml`/> <md:SingleLogoutService Binding=`urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP` Location=`https://example.com/realms/Posit/protocol/saml`/> <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat> <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat> <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat> <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat> <md:SingleSignOnService Binding=`urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST` Location=`https://example.com/realms/Posit/protocol/saml`/> <md:SingleSignOnService Binding=`urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect` Location=`https://example.com/realms/Posit/protocol/saml`/> <md:SingleSignOnService Binding=`urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP` Location=`https://example.com/realms/Posit/protocol/saml`/> <md:SingleSignOnService Binding=`urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact` Location=`https://example.com/realms/Posit/protocol/saml`/> </md:IDPSSODescriptor> </md:EntityDescriptor>


> rstudio-service.log: {`level`:`debug`,`msg`:`SAML request received
> with path /login`,`region`:`saml`,`time`:`2023-08-09T12:34:06.234Z`}
> {`level`:`debug`,`msg`:`Found a SAML encryption
> key`,`region`:`saml`,`time`:`2023-08-09T12:34:06.273Z`}
> {`level`:`debug`,`msg`:`Creating authentication
> request`,`region`:`saml`,`time`:`2023-08-09T12:34:06.273Z`}
> {`level`:`debug`,`msg`:`Returning authentication request as
> POST`,`region`:`saml`,`time`:`2023-08-09T12:34:06.273Z`}
> 
> Keycloak event Posit Realm: reason  Cannot_match_source_hash error   
> client_not_found
```

I just found this in my HAR file:

```
> {
>         "_initiator": {
>           "type": "other"
>         },
>         "_priority": "VeryHigh",
>         "_resourceType": "document",
>         "cache": {},
>         "connection": "8417",
>         "pageref": "page_3",
>         "request": {
>           "method": "POST",
>           "url": "https://key.kcc.tju.edu/realms/Posit/protocol/saml",
>           "httpVersion": "http/2.0",
>           "headers": [
>             {
>               "name": ":authority",
>               "value": "key.kcc.tju.edu"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": ":method",
>               "value": "POST"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": ":path",
>               "value": "/realms/Posit/protocol/saml"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": ":scheme",
>               "value": "https"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "accept",
>               "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "accept-encoding",
>               "value": "gzip, deflate, br"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "accept-language",
>               "value": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "cache-control",
>               "value": "max-age=0"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "content-length",
>               "value": "985"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "content-type",
>               "value": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "origin",
>               "value": "https://posit.jefferson.edu"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "referer",
>               "value": "https://posit.jefferson.edu/"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "sec-ch-ua",
>               "value": "\"Not/A)Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Microsoft Edge\";v=\"115\", \"Chromium\";v=\"115\""
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "sec-ch-ua-mobile",
>               "value": "?0"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "sec-ch-ua-platform",
>               "value": "\"macOS\""
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "sec-fetch-dest",
>               "value": "document"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "sec-fetch-mode",
>               "value": "navigate"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "sec-fetch-site",
>               "value": "cross-site"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "upgrade-insecure-requests",
>               "value": "1"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "user-agent",
>               "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0
> Safari/537.36 Edg/115.0.1901.200"
>             }
>           ],
>           "queryString": [],
>           "cookies": [],
>           "headersSize": -1,
>           "bodySize": 985,
>           "postData": {
>             "mimeType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
>             "text": "SAMLRequest=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%2BPHNhbWw6SXNzdWVyIEZvcm1hdD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOm5hbWVpZC1mb3JtYXQ6ZW50aXR5Ij5odHRwczovL3Bvc2l0LmplZmZlcnNvbi5lZHUvX19sb2dpbl9fL3NhbWw8L3NhbWw6SXNzdWVyPjxzYW1scDpOYW1lSURQb2xpY3kgRm9ybWF0PSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6bmFtZWlkLWZvcm1hdDpwZXJzaXN0ZW50IiBBbGxvd0NyZWF0ZT0idHJ1ZSIvPjwvc2FtbHA6QXV0aG5SZXF1ZXN0Pg%3D%3D&RelayState=id-5939a30955ef177438b1ca5c4b93ddce77e30aae",
>             "params": [
>               {
>                 "name": "SAMLRequest",
>                 "value": "PHNhbWxwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdCB4bWxuczpzYW1sPSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6YXNzZXJ0aW9uIiB4bWxuczpzYW1scD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOnByb3RvY29sIiBJRD0iaWQtNTkzOWEzMDk1NWVmMTc3NDM4YjFjYTVjNGI5M2RkY2U3N2UzMGFhZSIgVmVyc2lvbj0iMi4wIiBJc3N1ZUluc3RhbnQ9IjIwMjMtMDgtMDlUMTI6MzQ6MDYuMjczWiIgRGVzdGluYXRpb249Imh0dHBzOi8va2V5LmtjYy50anUuZWR1L3JlYWxtcy9Qb3NpdC9wcm90b2NvbC9zYW1sIiBBc3NlcnRpb25Db25zdW1lclNlcnZpY2VVUkw9Imh0dHBzOi8vcG9zaXQuamVmZmVyc29uLmVkdS9fX2xvZ2luX18vc2FtbC9hY3MiIFByb3RvY29sQmluZGluZz0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOmJpbmRpbmdzOkhUVFAtUE9TVCI%2BPHNhbWw6SXNzdWVyIEZvcm1hdD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOm5hbWVpZC1mb3JtYXQ6ZW50aXR5Ij5odHRwczovL3Bvc2l0LmplZmZlcnNvbi5lZHUvX19sb2dpbl9fL3NhbWw8L3NhbWw6SXNzdWVyPjxzYW1scDpOYW1lSURQb2xpY3kgRm9ybWF0PSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6bmFtZWlkLWZvcm1hdDpwZXJzaXN0ZW50IiBBbGxvd0NyZWF0ZT0idHJ1ZSIvPjwvc2FtbHA6QXV0aG5SZXF1ZXN0Pg%3D%3D"
>               },
>               {
>                 "name": "RelayState",
>                 "value": "id-5939a30955ef177438b1ca5c4b93ddce77e30aae"
>               }
>             ]
>           }
>         },
>         "response": {
>           "status": 400,
>           "statusText": "Bad Request",
>           "httpVersion": "http/2.0",
>           "headers": [
>             {
>               "name": "content-language",
>               "value": "en"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "content-length",
>               "value": "1733"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "content-security-policy",
>               "value": "frame-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; object-src 'none';"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "content-type",
>               "value": "text/html;charset=utf-8"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "date",
>               "value": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023 12:34:06 GMT"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "referrer-policy",
>               "value": "no-referrer"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "server",
>               "value": "nginx/1.20.1"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "strict-transport-security",
>               "value": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "x-content-type-options",
>               "value": "nosniff"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "x-frame-options",
>               "value": "SAMEORIGIN"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "x-robots-tag",
>               "value": "none"
>             },
>             {
>               "name": "x-xss-protection",
>               "value": "1; mode=block"
>             }
>           ],
>           "cookies": [],
>           "content": {
>             "size": 1733,
>             "mimeType": "text/html",
>             "text": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html class=\"login-pf\">\n\n<head>\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n    <meta
> http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />\n 
> <meta name=\"robots\" content=\"noindex, nofollow\">\n\n           
> <meta name=\"viewport\"
> content=\"width=device-width,initial-scale=1\"/>\n    <title>Sign in
> to SKCC Posit Server</title>\n    <link rel=\"icon\"
> href=\"/resources/svlv2/login/keycloak/img/favicon.ico\" />\n         
> <link
> href=\"/resources/svlv2/common/keycloak/web_modules/@patternfly/react-core/dist/styles/base.css\"
> rel=\"stylesheet\" />\n            <link
> href=\"/resources/svlv2/common/keycloak/web_modules/@patternfly/react-core/dist/styles/app.css\"
> rel=\"stylesheet\" />\n            <link
> href=\"/resources/svlv2/common/keycloak/node_modules/patternfly/dist/css/patternfly.min.css\"
> rel=\"stylesheet\" />\n            <link
> href=\"/resources/svlv2/common/keycloak/node_modules/patternfly/dist/css/patternfly-additions.min.css\"
> rel=\"stylesheet\" />\n            <link
> href=\"/resources/svlv2/common/keycloak/lib/pficon/pficon.css\"
> rel=\"stylesheet\" />\n            <link
> href=\"/resources/svlv2/login/keycloak/css/login.css\"
> rel=\"stylesheet\" />\n</head>\n\n<body class=\"\">\n<div
> class=\"login-pf-page\">\n    <div id=\"kc-header\"
> class=\"login-pf-page-header\">\n        <div
> id=\"kc-header-wrapper\"\n             class=\"\">SKCC Posit
> Server</div>\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"card-pf\">\n        <header
> class=\"login-pf-header\">\n                <h1 id=\"kc-page-title\"> 
> We are sorry...\n</h1>\n      </header>\n      <div
> id=\"kc-content\">\n        <div id=\"kc-content-wrapper\">\n\n\n     
> <div id=\"kc-error-message\">\n            <p
> class=\"instruction\">Invalid Request</p>\n        </div>\n\n\n\n     
> </div>\n      </div>\n\n    </div>\n  </div>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
>           },
>           "redirectURL": "",
>           "headersSize": -1,
>           "bodySize": -1,
>           "_transferSize": 2059,
>           "_error": null
>         },
>         "serverIPAddress": "10.187.131.138",
>         "startedDateTime": "2023-08-09T12:34:06.208Z",
>         "time": 98.80100000229199,
>         "timings": {
>           "blocked": 9.287999993294477,
>           "dns": 0.015000000000000013,
>           "ssl": 27.855999999999998,
>           "connect": 54.377,
>           "send": 0.19699999999999562,
>           "wait": 34.62999999677949,
>           "receive": 0.29400001221802086,
>           "_blocked_queueing": 9.049999993294477
>         }
>       },
```

Comment: You would have better luck contacting Posit support directly, or their community forum.

Comment: @Phil, I've been working with Posit support for a week and still getting the same error. I have posted on the Posit community forum, lots of views, no responses.